# Firestore create document if it doesn't exist, and listen to it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firebase web client for Firestore. I have a value `id` that is either the id for a document in a collection, or is `undefined`. I would like to either create a document with an id generated by Firestore (when `id` is undefined) or get the document if `id` is defined, and then listen to changes on the document. I want to be left with a function `unsubscribe` that I can call to detach the listener. Something like this:

```
let unsubscribe;
if (recipeId) {
  unsubscribe = db
    .collection("mycollection")
    .doc(id)
    .onSnapshot(doc => myFunction(doc));
} else {
  unsubscribe = db
    .collection("mycollection")
    .doc()
    .add()
    .then(docRef =>
      db
        .collection("mycollection")
        .doc(docRef.id)
        .onSnapshot(doc => myFunction(doc))
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.  It sounds like you have two different problems.  First, there is the issue of creating the document.  Second, there is the issue of listening to changes.  These problems do not really overlap.  You can't create documents by listening to them.  You use set() or add() to create new documents.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do each thing separately but I'm not sure how to string it all together. I've added an extended example of my attempt to illustrate how I am struggling. I think my problem is mostly just a general javascript one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new document with a random ID:

```
  const promise = db
    .collection("mycollection")
    .add({})
```

[add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) returns a promise with a DocumentReference.  You can then listen to that.

```
  promise.then((ref) => ref.onSnapshot(...))
```

Comment: Thanks, below is how I Implemented this, but I am getting `Uncaught FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.add() requires 1 argument, but was called with 0 arguments.`.    
     
    
`const unsubscribe = id
  ? db
      .collection("mycollection")
      .doc(id)
      .onSnapshot(doc => console.log(doc, doc.data()))
  : db
      .collection("mycollection")
      .add()
      .then(docRef => docRef.onSnapshot(doc => console.log(doc, doc.data())));`

Comment: OK, if you don't have initial contents to set, pass an empty object as my edit shows.